# Sort a list of objects with 2 props are String phoneNum and String name by frequency

Tags: java, file, sorting

I have 2 files like this:

Files Phones.

| phoneNumber | name |
| -------- | -------------- |
0963829993|Pham Thu Thao
0378225220|Nguyen Khanh Trinh
0909876987|Nguyen Huy Thong
0989562571|Bui Van Nghia
0768888995|Ly Viet Hang
Here is my code to read data from Phones.txt

```
Class Phone {
    private String phoneNum, name;
}
    Class PhoneList {
    private ArrayList<Phone> phones;
}

public void ReadDataFromFile(String filename) {
    try{
        FileReader f = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        String line = "";
        while (true)
        {   
            line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null)
                break;
            String txt[] = line.split("[\n\\|]");
            String phoneNumber = txt[0];
            System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phoneNumber);
            String customer = txt[1];
            System.out.println("Customner: " + customer);
            phones.add(new Phone(phoneNumber, customer));
        }
        f.close();
        br.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Calls.txt:
| From| To| Duration |
| -------- | -------------- | --------|
0963829993|0378225220|8
0378225220|0989562571|15
0963829993|0989562571|67
0989562571|0378225220|10
0989562571|0768888995|16
0768888995|0378225220|32
0963829993|0768888995|2

Here is my code to read data from Calls.txt:

```
    Class Call {
    private String from, to;
    private int duration;
}
    Class CallList {
    private ArrayList<Call> calls;
}


    public void ReadDataFromFile(String filename, PhoneList phoneList) {
    try{
        FileReader f = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        String line = "";
        while(true) {
            line = br.readLine();
            Phone phoneFrom = new Phone();
            Phone phoneTo = new Phone();
            int newDuration = 0;
            if(line == null)
                break;
            String txt[] = line.split("[\n\\|]");

            phoneFrom.setPhoneNumber(txt[0]);
            phoneTo.setPhoneNumber(txt[1]);
            newDuration = Integer.parseInt(txt[2]);
            System.out.println("From: " + phoneFrom.getPhoneNumber());
            System.out.println("To: " + phoneTo.getPhoneNumber());
            System.out.println("Duration: " + newDuration);
            calls.add(new Call(phoneFrom, phoneTo, newDuration));
        }
        f.close();
        br.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want to sort `PhoneList` phones by frequency appearing in file Calls.txt. I try to use `HashMap<Phone, Integer>` with Integer is the frequency of `phoneNumber` in Calls.txt, but it's not the same with my test requirement. The test output just have a list of `phoneNumber`.
I got stuck and need help, please help m. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this generics HashMap<String, Integer>

Whereas String is a combination of FromPhone+||+ToPhoneNumber and Value is No. of Calls Made.

Follow this for sorting by Value https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-hashmap-according-to-values/

// Sort the list

```
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer> >() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                           Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2)
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i want the output just has a list of Key, doesn't contains value. How can i do that

Comment: You can do that with streams. like yourlist.stream.map(listElement -> listElement.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: If you find it useful, pls mark this as correct answer or vote for it.